# add suffix number to a username avoid duplicate?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Add the suffix(number) to username, but if username already in the array or file increment the suffix by 1 then 2 if duplicate again so on...
I've already added the suffix using count. But I need to increment if already exist.

```
firstname = []
lastname  = []
firstchar = []
lastchar  = []
username  = []
rows      = []

CSV.open("userdata.csv", "wb") do |csv|  
    CSV.foreach("employeedata.csv", headers: true) do |row|  
        rows << row
    end

    count = 1

    rows.each do |line|
        firstname = line[0]
        lastname = line[1]
        firstchar = line[0][0].downcase
        lastchar = line[0][-1]
        username = lastname + firstchar + lastchar + "#{count}"
        name = firstname + lastname
        password = SecureRandom.hex(5)
        csv << [firstname] +  [lastname]  + [username] + [password]        
    end
end
```

Comment: You'll need to fix the formatting of your code block.

Comment: @robbpriestley I just did, let me know please

Comment: ok, that looks better, thanks

Comment: why are you 1. using array for firstname, lastname, firsstchar, lastchar, username. 
2. (optional) you could read employeedata.csv outside of userdata.csv block
3. use hash to hold the count of username

Comment: @twnaing : It is not correct that the OP uses arrays for `firstname` etc. While it is correct, that he unnecessarily initializes `firstname` with an empty array, this value is thrown away immediately inside the loop and replaced by a `String`. Actually, the first 6 lines of the program should be removed completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
rows      = []

CSV.foreach("employeedata.csv", headers: true) do |row|  
    rows << row
end

user_count = {}

CSV.open("userdata.csv", "wb") do |csv|  
    rows.each do |line|
        firstname = line[0]
        lastname = line[1]
        firstchar = line[0][0].downcase
        lastchar = line[0][-1]

        username = lastname + firstchar + lastchar
        user_count[username] = user_count.fetch(username){ 0 } + 1
        username = username + user_count[username].to_s

        name = firstname + lastname
        password = SecureRandom.hex(5)

        csv << [firstname] +  [lastname]  + [username] + [password]        
    end
end
```

1. read *employeedata.csv* outside *userdat.csv* file block
2. use `user_count` hash to hold the number of occurrence of username (lastname + firstchar + lastchar)
3. use [Hash fetch method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/fetch) to set the number of occurrence

Comment: Perfectly done @twnaing! Just had to add .to_s after user_count[username] to get out of the error "`+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String". Thanks